# Best Practice for synchronized jobs in Application clusters

Tags: mysql, node.js, cluster-computing, mariadb

We have got 3 REST-Applications within a cluster.
So each application server can receive requests from "outside".

Now we got timed events, which are analysing the database and add/remove rows from the database, send emails, etc.

The problem is, that each application server does start this timed events and it happens that 2 application server are starting this analysing job at the same time.

We got a sql table in the back.

Our idea was to lock a table within the sql database, when starting the job. If the table is locked, we exit the job, because an other application just started to analyse.

What's a good practice to insert some kind of semaphore ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use semaphores, you are over complicating things, just use message queueing, where you queue your tasks and get them executed in row.

Make ONLY one separate node/process/child_process to consume from the queue and get your task done.

Comment: If i got 4 application server, which will process the messages from the queue? where is the queue located ? It's own server ?

Comment: Don't let the 4 servers touch the database, anything you want to do with the database push it to the queue system (RabbitMQ, Beanstalk, etc, ..), and add a separate process/Node.js instance (be it on one of the existing servers or a new server) that consumes from the queue and handles the database operations sequentially (or you decide the flow as per your needs), but only this process is allowed to deal with the database.

Comment: The reason of clustering is to have redundancy, avoid single points of failure and scale vertically. 
Setting up a message queue, which costs me an additional database next to my replicating database clusters, additional nodejs process to keep alive, causes a lot of maintenance and complexity, doesnt it ?

Comment: What I understand from your question, in your current situation, is that ONLY one application server is allowed to edit the table in the Backend database at a time, that's why you want to avoid conflicts by introducing database locks/semaphores. and hold on ... We don't need to scale vertically, just add a consumer service on one of the servers, and authorized it to deal wit the DB, we don't need to scale vertically, we are still horizontal.

Comment: Regarding the need for additional maintenance and administration, yes it does, but not what you think, it's very minimal in case of Beanstalk, for example, and most of the queuing systems handle their databases internally, you don't have to install them or manage them manually, and even with complex queuing systems like RabbitMQ, your needs will be minimal, and still, things will not be very complicated. In conclusion, we want to achieve the decoupling of application server from DB analytics, and avoid locking mechanisms (in case you go for it), which will also be

Comment: No every application server is allowed to start a job, which is analysing the database and for example sends emails. There are currently 3 application server in one tier. Each is allowed to start the analysing, but i want to prevent 2 application servers start analysing at the same time, what will cause double emails

Comment: @KonstantinKrass, what you are saying is called serialization, you can't do 2 things in parallel. And that's what I have been telling you, everything is parallel and clustered except the part of DB, it has to be serial, this means we are on agreement.

Comment: btw, Redis has a really good pub/sub module, which can be used in similar situations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80253/discussion-between-konstantin-krass-and-securecurve).

Answer (score 0):

We (at a previous employer) used a database-based semaphore.  Each of several (for redundancy and load sharing) servers had the same set of cron jobs.  The first thing in each was a custom library call that did:

1. Connect to the database and check for (or insert) "I'm working on X".
2. If the flag was already set, then the cron job silently exited.
3. When finished, the flag was cleared.

The table included a timestamp and a host name -- for debugging and recovering from cron jobs that fail to finish gracefully.

I forget how the "test and set" was done.  Possibly an optimistic `INSERT`, then check for "duplicate key".